# Bold Greek text in a tabular (text mode)

Tags: bold

I simply do not know how to get the Greek text in bold.
Is the problem that I'm using the wrong macro for the tabular environment? OR, that I did not set the  fonts correctly?

I don't need everything in bold, just part of the line. I marked the place by using the \textbf macro (though this doesn't work).

Thank you!

MWE--

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[hmargin={1in,0.5in},vmargin=1in,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[series={A,B},nocritical,noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\ledlsnotesep=-50pt
\sidenotemargin{inner}
\textwidth = 500pt
\usepackage{setspace}
\AtBeginDocument{\doublespacing}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{SBL BibLit}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew,Contextuals=Alternate,Ligatures=Required]{SBL BibLit}

\begin{document}
\centering
\section*{Fragment VI.6 (Fol. 43): Psalm 31 Catena}
\beginnumbering
\begin{greek}
\noindent
\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont
\pstart
\begin{edtabularl}
&οὐ παραχρηῆμα τοῖς τῆς μετανοίας φαρμάκοις ἐχρήσατο· ἀλλὰ μετὰ τὸν ἔλεγχου τοῦ νάθαν·\\
&τοῦτο τοίνυν ἐνταῦθα βοᾶι· ἐπειδὴ παραυτίκα· δοξάμενος τὴν πληγὴν οὐχ ὑπέ\\
&δειξα τὸ ἔλκο\d{ς} τῶ ἱατρῶι ἀλλἀ ἐσίγησα κρύψαι πειρώμενος τοῦτο· κατεγήρασα\\
&βοῶν καὶ τῆς ἁμαρτίας κατηγορῶν \textbf{τὴν ἁμαρτίαν μου ἐγνώρισα καὶ τὴν ἁμαρτίαν μου}\\%HERE
\end{edtabularl}
\pend
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

Comment: SBL BibLit has no bold font, only regular

Comment: If a font family does not have bold font, then TeX can't give you bold (unless you give it more instructions). TeX does not have the Microsoft Word “B” button. You can “fake” the bold Greek in XeLaTeX, by writing `\newfontfamily\greekfont{SBL BibLit}[FakeBold=<decimal number>, Script=Greek, ...]`, where `FakeBold=0` changes nothing.

Comment: You might try Libertinus Serif, or any of the fonts from the Greek Font Society.

Comment: I have the same issue, except with a greek character that is embedded in an acronym that gets inserted into a header.  The header is bold text, but the greek character is not bold.